# How to open and close python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have a c++ program that reads sensor data from GPIO from a rpi.
I want to pass this data to my computer over Ethernet (cannot do Wi-Fi).

I am calling a python script from cpp to post 1 data byte to the socket.

I want to close the socket and end the py script, then do my next read in cpp, then call the same python script again to reopen the same socket and post the next data. How do I make this script modular?

Additionally (optional)

- (1) how do I do ubuntu sockets in cpp?
- (2) how do I pass a cpp variable to the transmit python script as the data in a cpp program?

The below script for transmit and receive work great in continuous mode, but I'd like a more async method to do this. If I attempt to close the socket and then reopen it, I get errors stating it is already open and the like.

I can send data over Ethernet by using

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
HOST='169.254.72.2'
PORT=2225
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr=s.accept()
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
print 'Connected by', addr
while True:
        conn.send('5')
s.close()
```

My receive python script (client) on the PC is this:

```
import socket
HOST='169.254.72.2'
PORT=2225
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while 1:
    a=time.clock()
    data=s.recv(1)
    print data
s.close()
```

Comment: Why do you want to close the socket between the bytes? Isn't it easier to just keep it open? Or are the data coming very sparsely? Along the same lines, wouldn't it be better to make the PC the server side, and then just have your RPi connect to that one to transmit one byte, then disconnect?

Comment: You're a genius. PC Server and rpi client is the way to go